# React: Custom Component in double map loop don't render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

i am struggling to a problem in React.
I am working on a modal Form using the Material-UI Field.
Each Field type like **Select, Text and Shrink** have their own Component.
To handle more complex event like **display more field depending on a field's value**, i create a new component **FormField** with a main Field and all the other field that will be display.

I declare the component like this:

```
<FormField 
         nodeField={values[4]} 
         required={values[4].required} 
         childField={[values.slice(5,7),values.slice(7,values.length)]} 
         arrayConditionDisplayChild={[(element)=>element.value == "Factor and Offset",(element)=>element.value == "2 points calibration"]}
/>
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Field from './Field.jsx';

export default function FormField(props)
{
    const [arrayCurrentIndex, setArrayCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
    const [arrayChildField, setArrayChildField] = useState(props.childField); // Hook comportant un tableau de tableau d'objet contenant chacun les informations de l'ensemble des champs enfants
    const [nodeField, setNodeField] = useState(props.nodeField);

    const [isComplete, setIsComplete] = useState(false);

    console.log("form field");

    const handleFieldChange = (fieldId, valueChange) => {
        console.log("handleFieldChange")
        if (nodeField.id == fieldId)
        {
            console.log(valueChange);
            let newNodeObject = Object.assign({},nodeField);
            newNodeObject.value = valueChange;
            console.log(newNodeObject);
            setNodeField(newNodeObject);
        }
        else
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < arrayChildField.length ; i++)
            {
                let j = arrayChildField[i].findIndex((element)=>element.id == fieldId);
                if (j != -1)
                {
                    //JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nodeField)
                    let newChildArray = arrayChildField[i][j].slice(0);
                    newChildArray[i][j].value = valueChange;
                    setArrayChildField(newChildArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{

    },[JSON.stringify(nodeField),JSON.stringify(arrayChildField)])

    return(
        <div>
            <Field objectField={props.nodeField} isRequired={props.required} handleFieldChange={handleFieldChange}/>
            {
                arrayChildField.map((childField, index) => (
                    props.arrayConditionDisplayChild[index](nodeField) && 
                    childField.map((field) => {
                        <div key={field.id}>
                            <Field objectField={field} isRequired={props.required} handleFieldChange={handleFieldChange}/>
                        </div>
                    })
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import FormText from './FormText.jsx';
import FormShrink from './FormShrink.jsx';
import FormSelect from './FormSelect.jsx';

export default function Field(props)
{
    console.log(props);
    switch(props.objectField.type)
    {
        case "Text":
            console.log("text");
            return (
                <FormText id={props.objectField.id} label={props.objectField.label} required={props.isRequired} onChange={props.handleFieldChange}/>
            );
            break;
        case "Shrink":
            console.log("Shrink");
            return (
                <FormShrink key={props.objectField.id} id={props.objectField.id} label={props.objectField.label} required={props.isRequired} condition={props.objectField.condition} onChange={props.handleFieldChange}/>
            );
            break;
        case "Select":
            console.log("Select");
            return (
                <FormSelect id={props.objectField.id} label={props.objectField.label} required={props.isRequired} currency={props.objectField.currency} onChange={props.handleFieldChange}/>
            );
            break;
    }
}
```

Here I use the Hook **[nodeField]** in the return to check if there is the value of the main **Field** respond to one of the condition in an props **arrayConditionDisplayChild.**
I work with a another Hook **[arrayChildField]** witch is an array of an array of object and each element of the first array represent all the information for the child field to display.
If one of the condition is true then a new loop map is starting creating new Component **Field** with a key.

```
return(
        <div>
            <Field objectField={props.nodeField} isRequired={props.required} handleFieldChange={handleFieldChange}/>
            {
                arrayChildField.map((childField, index) => (
                    props.arrayConditionDisplayChild[index](nodeField) && 
                    childField.map((field) => {
                        <div key={field.id}>
                            <Field objectField={field} isRequired={props.required} handleFieldChange={handleFieldChange}/>
                        </div>
                    })
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
```

I don't get it why the main Component field render correctly but the nested Field don't.
Note that i have tried to replace the nested Field component by a regular **h1 or p** element with a key and it actually work.

So i guess that might **be a problem about rendering Custom Component in a double loop.**
What did i do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i feel really really dumb, i never checked my component FormShrink and his conditional rendering was

```
return (
      active && <TextField className="textfield" error={errorFormShrink} id={props.id} label={props.required ? props.label + " *" : props.label} type="number" InputLabelProps={{shrink: true,}} variant="filled" helperText={helperText} onChange={handleChange}/>
    );
```

witch active was false at the start.
Thanks you Waleed Nassir for helping me still.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Curly Braces, yon need to use return () like this:

```
{
                arrayChildField.map((childField, index) => (
                    props.arrayConditionDisplayChild[index](nodeField) && 
                    childField.map((field) => {
    return
                      (  <div key={field.id}>
                            <Field objectField={field} isRequired={props.required} handleFieldChange={handleFieldChange}/>
                        </div>)
                    })
                ))
            }
```

other wise you can use like that:

```
{
                arrayChildField.map((childField, index) => (
                    props.arrayConditionDisplayChild[index](nodeField) && 
                    childField.map((field) => (
                        <div key={field.id}>
                            <Field objectField={field} isRequired={props.required} handleFieldChange={handleFieldChange}/>
                        </div>
                    ))
                ))
            }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, sadly i have already tried these 2 syntax but none of them work for me

Comment: did you check your 2nd map is working or not?

Comment: Yes i did check my 2nd map, it even enter the Field component and into the switch condition but it is just stuck at it